# c# Serializable object XML file location

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have this code which creates an XML file and stores whether a checkbox is true or false. It is read on application startup

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("Store", Namespace = "")]
public class Credentials
{
    public Credentials() { }

    public bool checkBox1State { get; set; }


    public static Credentials ReadCredentials()
    {
        XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Credentials));
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("Credentials.xml");
        Credentials data = new Credentials();
        data = (Credentials)reader.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
        return data;
    }

    public static void WriteCredentials(Credentials data)
    {
        XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Credentials));
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Credentials.xml");
        writer.Serialize(file, data);
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

My program reads and writes perfectly from the xml file. However I noticed this is stored in the root directory where the .exe was launched from. Typically, this will be in the program files which needs elevated permissions to write to.

As such, I would like to store this file in the user's AppData folder. What modifications are needed on my code to allow for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resolve the path to the AppData directory of the current user. Either with the SpecialFolder Enum

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Credentials.xml")
```

or by expanding the environment variable

```
string fileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%AppData%\Credentials.xml");
```

And use it instead of the realtive filename

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great. Dunno how I overlooked this though